# Maven missing artifact when adding powermock

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, powermock

I'm using eclipse and managing my dependency with Maven. I would like to use powermock in my project.

my project is depend on another project which is using Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE.
I add this project into maven.

When I add a powermock dependency my pom.xml said my project missing artifacts. But when I checked my "Maven dependencies" all the jars are there.

I've tried to "Maven Clean", open and close projects, rebuild it, but still everytime I add powermock into my pom, it said missing artifacts.

Does anyone had this problem and resolve it?

Thanks,

Comment: What artifact is missing?  Can you post relevant lines from the logs as well as the pom?

Comment: @user293655: Try `Update Maven dependencies` after adding powermock dependency.

Comment: You can also use the maven dependency plugin to find out whether it's really missing, or a problem with your eclipse config.  try running `mvn dependency:analyze` from the command-line and it'll give you a breakdown.

Comment: The missing artifacts are from another projects, there are hundreds of them.
I've tried update maven dependencies, does not work.
I also tried to close the other project and just have the other project installed in the repository, still no luck.

Comment: I change the eclipse into an older version of Indigo. And it works now.
Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

See here for how to add powermock (mockito/JUnit) to your POM:
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven